# Let page override quirks mode set in developer toolbar

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

By using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

I am able to ensure that the Document mode is IE9. However, when I set the Document Mode to Quirks using the developer tools and then bring up my application, it remains in Quirks Mode instead of going into IE9 mode.

Is there a way to override the settings of Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The F12 tools setting overrides the page default and persists for the life of the page or the life of the F12 tools session.

If you'd rather not choose the default from the document mode drop-down, you can do one of two things:

- Copy the URL into the address bar of a new tab
- Press F12 to close and then re-open the F12 tools

Either way, the page should revert to its natural document mode.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S.  Tested in current installs of IE11.  Mileage may vary in earlier versions of IE.